# jQuery: multiple references to one footnote, link back to the referring ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

been struggling to solve this as I'm completely newbie to JS. What I'm trying to achieve:

- To have multiple references to a footnote (can't avoid this).
- Be able to reference back to the correct ID

My code looks like this.

```js
//convention
//ID of reference to footnote= Caller ID
//ID of the footnote= FN ID
//HREF of the footnote that refer back to the caller ID = FN HREF

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".art-fn-ref").one('click', function(e) {
    //001 - check if the Caller ID match a pattern (mulfn#)
    $('[id^=mulfn]').filter(function() {
      //002 - copy the 001 ID
      //003 - store the original HREF and ID of the footnote (FN HREF and FN ID)
      //004 - replace the FN HREF with HREF that points out to the correct caller ID
      //005 - once the "modified" FN HREF is clicked, restore it back to the original FN HREF
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <p>Lorem<a id="fn1-ref" href="#fn1" title="link to footnote" class="art-fn-ref"><sup>1</sup></a>.</p>
  <p>ipsum<a id="fn2-ref" href="#fn2" title="link to footnote" class="art-fn-ref"><sup>2</sup></a></p>
  <p>dolor<a id="mulfn1-1-ref" href="#fn3" title="link to footnote" class="art-fn-ref"><sup>3</sup></a>.</p>
  <p>sit<a id="mulfn1-2-ref" href="#fn3" title="link to footnote" class="art-fn-ref"><sup>3</sup></a>.</p>
</section>
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="fn1" href="#fn1-ref" title="link to main text" class="art-fn"><sup>1</sup></a> Footnote 1</li>
    <li><a id="fn2" href="#fn2-ref" title="link to main text" class="art-fn"><sup>2</sup></a> Foonote 2</li>
    <li><a id="fn3" href="#mulfn1-1-ref" title="link to main text" class="art-fn"><sup>3</sup></a> Foonote 3</li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

For example. There are two references to footnote 3 with the following ID "mulfn1-1-ref" & "mulfn1-2-ref". Suppose that I click the "mulfn1-2-ref" and it took me to "fn3" If I click the fn3, i need it to take me back to "mulfn1-2-ref" instead of "mulfn1-1-ref".

How to do this? Please help.

Comment: Why don't you just add a single "Back to Text" button?

Comment: I can, but isn't that mean that I need to have as many back to text buttons as the reference I have? What I'm trying to do is to have just one button or href elements that can be updated using jquery. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I mean that you only need one "link to main text" -- just have it appear dynamically in the corner of the page whenever you click on a footnote, and disappear again when you click it. You will still need to use jQuery to update the value stored in the link, but at least you will only have a single link to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on one of the top links

- add a `data-href` attribute on the footnote link it linked to with the ID of the referring link
- add a `click` event listener to the footnote link that disables the default action and sets the `window.location` to the `data-href` value, then removes the event listener

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".art-fn-ref").on('click', function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id'),
          $target = $($(this).attr('href'));
        $target.attr('data-href','#'+id);
        $target.on('click',function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');
          $(this).off('click');
        })
    });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
blockquote,
pre,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: "";
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.art-fn-ref {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    padding: 1px;
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: 75%
}
a {
}

.art-fn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#4CAF50;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    padding: 1px;
    font-size: 75%
}

p {
    padding: 6px 0 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
        <p>Lorem<a id="fn1-ref" href="#fn1" title="link to footnote" class="art-fn-ref"><sup>1</sup></a>.</p>
        <p>ipsum<a id="fn2-ref" href="#fn2" title="link to footnote" class="art-fn-ref"><sup>2</sup></a></p>
        <p>dolor<a id="mulfn1-1-ref" href="#fn3" title="link to footnote" class="art-fn-ref"><sup>3</sup></a>.</p>
        <p>sit<a id="mulfn1-2-ref" href="#fn3" title="link to footnote" class="art-fn-ref"><sup>3</sup></a>.</p>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <ul>
            <li><a id="fn1" href="#fn1-ref" title="link to main text" class="art-fn"><sup>1</sup></a> Footnote 1</li>
            <li><a id="fn2" href="#fn2-ref" title="link to main text" class="art-fn"><sup>2</sup></a> Foonote 2</li>
            <li><a id="fn3" href="#mulfn1-1-ref" title="link to main text" class="art-fn"><sup>3</sup></a> Foonote 3</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
```

Comment: thank you. it works when i run the code snippet here. But when i try it on fiddle, it didn't work.

Comment: @garagnoth if you'd like me to look at it, give me the link.

Comment: I must have done something stupid. It works in fiddle now. https://jsfiddle.net/garagnoth/wwb8nc0L/